# Как сделать отбор по колонке ДАТА и текущей дате и -5 дней?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

У меня есть таблица

```
ФИО МЕЙЛ ДАТА
Яковлев yakovlev@ma.ru 2.06
Рубцов rubcov@ma.ru 25.10
Кравцов kravcov@ma.ru 23.10
```

Как мне написать запрос к DataFrame что бы он убрал из таблицы людей у кого сегодняшняя дата и -5 в последующем, совпадает с колонкой ДАТА? К примеру у человека ДР 02.06 , так вот за 5 дней и до  03.06 он из таблички должен исчезать?

Comment: не понятно. что значит, "исчезать за 5 дней" до сегодня? приведите больше исходных данных и желаемый результат.

Comment: у человека ДР к примеру 23.10, вот за 5 дней , 5 дней подряд идет оповещение всем, кроме именинников

Comment: pdex.assign(dt=pdex.to_datetime(pdex["ДАТА"] + f."{today.year}", dayfirst=True))
                                                             
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `pd` - это alias для `pandas`. Поэтому замените `pdex.to_datetime` --> `pd.to_datetime` PS если хотите обратиться к автору комментария, то укажите имя пользователя с `@` вначале - например: @MaxU, ...

Comment: @MaxU он на ковычки f."{today.year}" ругается, если делаю так  .assign(dt=pd.to_datetime(pdex["DRT"] + today.year, dayfirst=True)) то в dt колонки какая то шляпа 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002036

Comment: @user3119496, какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: @MaxU python 3 использую

Comment: @user3119496, у вас версия Python < 3.6 ? Начиная с Python 3.6 "f-string" должны правильно работать...

Comment: @MaxU да я уже и так и так пробовал, не дает он мне ничего, говорит синтаксическая ошибка и на " указывает. Python 3.5.3

Comment: @user3119496, исправил ответ для Python версий < 3.6

Comment: @MaxU теперь такая ошибка numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Comment: какой вывод у команды: `print(pdes.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @MaxU Completed
FUL      object
MAIL     object
DRT     float64
RUM      object
dtype: object

Comment: `DRT` - это, надо полагать, `ДАТА`  в вопросе? Если это так, то расскажите как вы получили данный фрейм?

Comment: @MaxU да все верно DRT = ДАТА, я данный фрейм получил путем, pdf to Excel ,а потом из excel вытащил данные в df

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108826/discussion-between-maxu-and-user3119496).

Comment: можете выложить ваш Excel на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @MaxU https://yadi.sk/i/j0T0_8-KFHiIpg

Answer (score 2):

Если преобразовать столбец `ДАТА` к типу `datetime64`, добавив текущий год, то задача сводится к сравнению дат:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT, timedelta

filename = r"D:\download\abc.xlsx"
dob_col = "День\nрождения"

# читаем ДР как строки, а не как вещественные числа
df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=1, dtype={dob_col: str})

days = 5
today = DT.today().date()
dt_from = today - timedelta(days=days)

res = (df
       .assign(dt=pd.to_datetime(df[dob_col] + ".{}".format(today.year), dayfirst=True))
       .query("not (@dt_from <= dt <= @today)")
       .drop(columns="dt"))
```

---

результат:

```
In [119]: res
Out[119]:
   No               ФИ           Направление работы                            ФИО   e-mail  IP       Мобильный День\nрождения  \
0   1   Иванов\nЛеонид                 Директор ДСМ         Иванов Леонид Павлович  a@mt.ru  19  +79160000\n000           16.1
1   2  Иванов\nВиталий            business teamlead       Иванов Виталий\nИванович  p@mt.ru  11  +79160000\n000           2.08
2   3   Иванов\nИльдар  Управление продуктом (сеть)         Иванов Ильдар Иванович  t@mt.ru  10  +79160000\n000          26.06
4   5  Иванов\nАлексей   Управление продуктом (Гео)  Иванов Алексей\nАлександрович  v@mt.ru  16  +79160000\n000          25.05
5   6      Иванов Иван    Управление продуктом (RA)           Иванов Иван Иванович  k@mt.ru  14  +79160000\n000           7.04
6   7    Иванов\nАнтон    Управление продуктом (RA)      Иванов Антон\nГеннадьевич  z@mt.ru  19  +79160000\n000           5.08

  Login\nAD Комна\nта  Табельный\nномер
0         t         3           6888888
1         v         3            488888
2         i         3           2388888
4        aa         3           6888888
5         g    уволен           6888888
6        dd         4           6888888
```

Comment: А так `today = DT.today().date()` разве не работает? Ручное обнуление времени как-то уж очень некрасиво выглядит :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, так тоже работает, спасибо! Не был уверен, что Pandas поймет переменную типа `datetime.date`. Проверил - работает)